# Several VSTO Projects in same Solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto

What are the options if I want to deploy add-ins for various Office Apps?
Can my `Solution` contain several VSTO `Projects`? For example one Excel AddIn, one Word AddIn, and one PowerPoint AddIn.

Should I have/need each AddIn in a separate `Solution`? In particular if I run Excel, and later run Word without closing Excel: do I end up with two distinct instances running in parallel?

Some of my classes are used by several AddIns, so it is more convenient to have everything in one `Solution`. That would also make deployment and updates easier. However I could always export the classes in a standalone DLL `Project` and reference that DLL in each `Solution`.

Comment: This question is probably too broad and opinion-based. [For example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing). Google would be a better resource for this; SO is for specific questions (though the [question help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doesn't seem to do a great job of explaining this any more).

Comment: Google was not very usefull as most topics refer to having several Excel projects included in the same solution for compatibility issues (one 2010 project and one 2013-2016). Here I would like to know if (and how) I can have Excel and Word live and communicate together. I am trying to define the high level architecture of my AddIn. Any pros and cons of having two solutions or all-in-one are welcome.

Comment: Typically, questions about best-practice are too opinionated to make for good SO posts.  However, to answer your question about whether or not you can add multiple to the same solution, I certainly can't imagine why not, or why that would even be discouraged.  I've never created a VSTO project before, so I'm not an expert on it, but I assume it just builds to a DLL anyway, like any other class library, so it's hard to imagine why multiple in the same solution would be an issue.  I don't know of any project types where multiple of the same type are disallowed.

Comment: Question has been slightly refrased to adress the concerns re "best practice". However I remain stuck. @StevenDoggart, at the moment I am unable to get two VSTO running smoothly if within the same solution. That is because VSTO Projects are different in the sense that they are called by a separate App (Office Word, Excel, etc). I am unsure how the call is made when Excel is launched: for example, does it call the solution or the project? Then if Excel is on and I start Word, will Word be able to take over at least some controls over the solution or will it start a new instance?

Comment: One key feature with VSTOs is the Office Ribbon. At the moment I am unable to get two Ribbons working together, but this might be due to a separate issue, for which I asked a question about in this separate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676630/vsto-ribbon-not-showing-when-starting-from-blank-solution. Indeed, having 2 VSTO in one solution means having at least one of them Added after the solution was created, which causes the problem adressed in the above-mentionned post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to follow up on your comments, publishing and execution are project-based. That's why Visual Studio has a StartUp project. So it seems like multiple projects in one solution should work.

But if you want to debug multiple add-ins at the same time you're going to need two instances of Visual Studio, so you might as well keep them in separate solutions. If you want to debug only one, you could publish one, run it, and then launch the other from VS.

If you're sharing code among them, You still can, and should, keep a common project loaded in both and afaik it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is what I had in mind as well. However I could not run any tests as I was unable to have both Word and Excel VSTOs showing the Ribbon when loaded. This has just been resolved (for anyone interested, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676630/vsto-ribbon-not-showing-when-starting-from-blank-solution). I have managed to debug both VSTO projects from a single VS solution: before compiling, set the relevant VSTO project as "StartUp", and it will run the relevant App (Excel/Word) accordingly. I have not looked yet at what happens if I then open the other App..

Comment: I've tried dozens of different configurations (adding a reference to the Word VSTO inside the Excel VSTO, compiling my CLass Library separately and manually pasting it over the ClickOnce folder, etc). It looks like there are two problems: only the "StartUp" project is registered with the registry. Manually adding a reference to the COM AddIn .dll file for the VSTO which was not "StartUp" fails: 'C:\...\...\MyVSTO.dll' is not a valid Office Add-in.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you're saying. It kind of sounds like you're trying to access a Word add-in from an Excel add-in. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2017](That may be possible), but you might be able to get by with a common class library referenced in both add-ins. Can you share a use case?

Comment: No doubts you struggle to understand what I am trying to say; VSTO is quite new for me (been with VBA for 10 years): I lack control and vocabulary over Solutions/Project/Compilation. Simple case study: 1 Excel AddIn Project, 1 Word AddIn Project, 1 DLL Project. Excel has a reference to the DLL, Word has a reference to the DLL. The DLL stores User Settings (for example Language). I know how to open an Excel file from Word and vice-cersa, but that is not what I am trying to do here.

Comment: I could actually even probably live without sharing User Settings between the two AddIns (ok the user will have to replicate its preferences on both AddIns but thats not the end of the world). However I would really like to be able to deploy both AddIns with a unique ClickOnce setup.

Comment: For that case you would want to add a project reference to each Add-In project. Right click on References > Add Reference > Projects > Choose your DLL project. Put your prefs management code there. You'll have to define where it's stored and perform the de/serialization (look up the Serializable class attribute) yourself.